# How to get the total number of first level comments of a youtube video?

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

Do you know how I can get the total number of first level comments ( with no replies) from a youtube video? I know that we can get all comments, but just in batches of maximum 100 items so if you have a video with 10 000 comments you will have to wait a coupe of minutes.
This method returns all comments (replies included).

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_KEY

Even on the youtube page you can see that number of comments represents the comments + replies.

If I need to give you more details, please ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want only number of top level comment, if I am not wrong in understanding of your question

Comment: Exactly. Do you have any idea on how can I do this without fetching all the comments? Than you!